# Использование @PreAuthorize на вложенном методе

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring

В веб-приложении используется Spring WebMVC и Spring Security. Возник вопрос, почему не работает аннотация @PreAuthorize, если повесить её на вложенный метод в классе контроллера:

```
@GetMapping(value= "/method")
public String exampleForMethodPreAuthorize() {
    if(methodController()){
        return "forMethodPreAuthorize";
    }
    else return null;
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public final boolean methodController(){
    return true;
}
```

Код выше не работает, т.е. метод срабатывает для любых пользователей, даже тех, кто не имеет полномочий доступа Admin. Хотя, если эту аннотацию расположить на самом методе контроллера:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")      
@GetMapping(value= "/method")
public String exampleForMethodPreAuthorize() {

   return "forMethodPreAuthorize";        
}
```

то в этом случае всё работает отлично.
  Естественно, в файле конфигурации сервлет-контекста используется component-scan и

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Какая версия spring security ?
4.2 Работает такое.

Comment: последняя версия, Spring 5.0.2, Spring Security 5.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Пожалуй, разверну оба варианта своего ответа, так как, может быть не в этом конкретном случае, но надо учитывать все возможные причины такого поведения.*

Во-первых, Spring заворачивает бин контроллера в прокси-объект, перехватывающий все вызовы к методам и проверяющий соответствие прав доступа выражению в аннотации `@PreAuthorize`. Но прокси-объект не может перехватывать вызовы внутри целевого объекта, только вызовы извне. С этим можно столкнулся при использовании многих аннотаций, не только аннотаций Spring Security.

Во-вторых, в приложениях использующих Spring Security, до того как попасть в [dispatcher servlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet) и после к контроллеру, запрос проходит через цепочку [сервлетных фильтров](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В частности, через [FilterSecurityInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/intercept/FilterSecurityInterceptor.html), который как раз проверяет истинность [security expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) и отбрасывает запрос ещё до того, как контроллер получит управление, если выражение ложно.

*Поэтому я удивлён, честно говоря, что Spring Security делает ещё одну проверку при вызове метода.*

Comment: Sergey, спасибо за ответ. Но у меня же аннотация @PreAuthorize висит не на классе контроллера, а на одном из его методов, который вызывается внутри другого его метода. Если прокси-объект оборачивающий бин контроллера не перехватывает внутрение вызовы методов, то как тогда можно альтернативно реализовать такую логику?

Comment: Sergey, предыдущая версия вашего ответа мне кажется была ближе к истине. Не могу согласится, Spring Security обеспечивает безопасность не только за счёт сервлет-фильтра для URL запросов, но и отдельно на уровне методов. Как раз при использовании данной аннотации. И метод с такой аннотацией может вообще быть в любом классе, не только в классе контроллера.

Answer (score 2):

Sergey, ваш первый ответ натолкнул меня на мысль, благодаря чему я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Действительно, бин контроллера проксируется и видимо из-за этого внутренние вызовы методов не проверяются на аннотацию @PreAuthorize. Потребовалось в отдельном классе, аннотированном @Component, создать метод, который предназначен вызываться из метода контроллера и инжектировать бин данного класса в класс контроллера при помощи @Autowired. Дело в том, что механизм использования аннотации @PreAuthorize сам основан на создании прокси для бина соответствующего класса и проверкой этим прокси вызовов методов на наличие данной аннотации. Поэтому метод с аннотацией @PreAuthorize должен быть в классе-бине. Примерно так:

```
@Controller
public class MvcController {

    @Autowired
    SomeClass someClass;

    @GetMapping(value= "/externalMethod")
    public String exampleForExternalMethodPreAuthorize() {
        if(someClass.externalMethod()){
            return "forMethodPreAuthorize";
        }
        else return null;
    }
}

@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public boolean externalMethod() {
        return true;
    }
}
```